# Martingale and a sequence of non-negative real numbers.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, random-walk

> Let $X_0,X_1,\dots$ be integrable and non-negative random variables. Let $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_0,\dots,X_n)$ and suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n)\leq b_n + X_n$ where $(b_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers with $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n<\infty$.
>
> Show that $X_\infty:=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}X_n$ exists almost surely and $X_\infty$ is integrable.
>
> (Hint: Consider the $Y_n=X_n+\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty b_k$)

So if I can show that $X_n$ is a sub- or supermartingale and that $\sup E(|X_n|)<\infty$ then I know that $X_\infty:=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}X_n$ exists almost surely and $X_\infty$ is integrable. Unfortunately I don't know how to show that it's a sub- or a supermartingale since the $b_n$ are unkown.

I tried to work with the hint $Y_n=X_n+\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty b_k$
$$E(Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=E(X_{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty b_k\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=E(X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n)+\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty b_k$$

But I don't see how this is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Y_n \ge 0$, if you can show that $Y_n$ is a supermartingale, the you are done. In fact,
\begin{align*}
E(Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n) &= E(X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n) + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty b_k\\
&\le X_n + b_n + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty b_k= Y_n.
\end{align*}
Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Y_n$ exists, and, consequently, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n$ exists.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any hint for integrability of $X_\infty$? I tried Fatou's lemma: $E(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} X_n)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}E(X_n)$ but I don't see how to show that this is finite.

Comment: That can be inferred from the fact that $E(Y_n)$ is decreasing, and the relationship between $X_n$ and $Y_n$.